# Shailan Dropdown 3rd level working in chrome but not in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I was using shailan dropdown menu plugin for my wordpress site and all was fine until i introduced depth 3 items.They seem to working fine in Chrome but level 3 (Services->Corporate Services->Verticals) doesn't appear in IE.

```
    div.shailan-dropdown-menu table,div.shailan-dropdown-menu tbody,div.shailan-dropdown-menu tr,div.shailan-dropdown-menu td,div.shailan-dropdown-menu ul,div.shailan-dropdown-menu li,div.dropdown-horizontal-container,ul.dropdown *{margin:0;padding:0;border:0}
.shailan-dropdown-menu{position:relative;z-index:597}
ul.dropdown,ul.dropdown li,ul.dropdown ul{list-style:none;margin:0;padding:0}
ul.dropdown li{position:relative;display:inline;vertical-align:middle;zoom:1}
ul.dropdown li ul{position:absolute;z-index:598}
ul.dropdown li.hover,ul.dropdown li:hover{cursor:default}ul.dropdown > li{float:left}
ul.dropdown li a{padding:.3em .8em;cursor:pointer}
ul.dropdown ul{position:absolute;top:100%;left:0px}
ul.dropdown ul li{float:none;display:list-item;list-style:none}
ul.dropdown ul ul{top:1px;left:99%;z-index:600000;}
ul.dropdown a:active,ul.dropdown a:focus{outline-style:none}
* html ul.dropdown li{height:1px}
ul.dropdown ul li,ul.dropdown-vertical{margin-left:0px}
ul.dropdown ul,ul.dropdown li.hover ul ul,ul.dropdown li.hover ul ul ul,ul.dropdown `li.hover ul ul ul ul,ul.dropdown li.hover ul ul ul ul ul,ul.dropdown ul,ul.dropdown li:hover ul ul,ul.dropdown li:hover ul ul ul,ul.dropdown li:hover ul ul ul ul,ul.dropdown li:hover ul ul ul ul ul{display:none}`
ul.dropdown ul ul ul ul ul ul{display:none!important}
.dm-align-right table{float:right}
.dm-align-left table{float:left}
ul.dropdown-horizontal.dropdown-align-right ul{right:0;left:auto}
ul.dropdown-horizontal.dropdown-align-right ul ul{right:99%;left:auto;z-index:6000000}
ul.dropdown-vertical.dropdown-align-left ul{top:1px;left:99%;right:auto}
ul.dropdown-vertical.dropdown-align-right ul{top:1px;right:99%;left:auto}
ul.dropdown-vertical li{float:none;display:block}
.clearfix:after{clear:both;content:".";display:block;height:0;visibility:hidden}
* html > body .clearfix{display:block;width:100%}* html .clearfix{height:1%}
```

Heres the site at http://umanahr.com/index.php

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with shailan, so the solution that I found was to create an ie.css then add the code below. Hope this would help.

```
.shailan-dropdown-menu-widget{z-index: 9999;}
ul.dropdown ul {
filter:none;
}
```

Comment: where will ie.css` go ?, how can I link it to all the pages ? at the header ?, would be great if you could tell us, or gives us a reference... Thank you.